# How to pass property value dynamically to sql tag in liquibase changelog

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, liquibase

I'm currently assigning a predefined property value to some tag's attributes, but I want to use it as well inside xml tags. Below is an example based on Liquibase documentation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd"
>

    <property  name="schema.name"  value="DBPECG"/>

    <changeSet id="20201005103200-1" author="felipe.rudolfe" objectQuotingStrategy="QUOTE_ALL_OBJECTS">
        <createTable schemaName="${schema.name}" tableName="TB_IES" >
         .
         .
         .
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

And here is what I want to do. I want to use schema.name in a way such as this, **inside sql tag**:

```
<changeSet id="20201005103200-3" author="felipe.rudolfe" objectQuotingStrategy="LEGACY">
    <sql>
        ALTER TABLE ${schema.name}.TB_IES ADD CONSTRAINT...
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: XML usually has a root element that surrounds the tags; however, your example you have a `property` tag and a `changeSet` tag at the root. Have you given the complete structure? Or is there a surrounding root tag?

Comment: Yeah there is, I'm gonna correct it. Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liquibase allows dynamic substitution of properties in changelog files. We can configure multiple properties inside a file and then use them wherever required. In your case, we can just configure property `"schemaName"` with some value and then use it in changelog file using `${schemaName}` syntax.

Liquibase assigns or prioritizes value for configured property in below order:

1. As an attribute passed to your liquibase runner.
2. As a JVM sytem property
3. As an environment variable
4. As a CLI attribute if you are running liquibase through command line
5. In liquibase.properties file
6. In the parameters block (property element of the DATABASECHANGELOG
   table)

You can do it as below example code snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

    <changeSet author="author" id="some-unique-id" context="some-context">
        **Your SQL query/ transactional logic goes here**
        <sql>
             ALTER TABLE ${schemaName}.TB_IES ADD CONSTRAINT...
        </sql>
    </changeSet>
    
</databaseChangeLog>
```

In `liquibase.properties` file, I will configure this property as follows:

```
schemaName=DBPECG
```

***Note:*** above example is using 1 property (schemaName). You can use only even more than that.

If you need help with creating `"liquibase.properties"` file, visit [this link](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/creating-config-properties.html)

Cheers!